# Simple makefile for compiling a shared object library file

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, x86-64

I need a very simple makefile to compile a shared object library file (*.so). I also need to know how to pass optimization parameters like -O2 and -O3. I tried to search for simple examples using google, but all examples are twisted.

I don't need to create any version like *.so.1.0 but only a simple *.so file. My project would have multiple files, so I need an example which compiles multiple files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest makefile that I can think of that does what you want:

```
CXXFLAGS += -fPIC
CXXFLAGS += -O3
x.so: x.o y.o
    g++ -shared $^ -o $@
```

In the alternative, you may want to use more of make's built-in rules and variables:

```
CXXFLAGS += -fPIC
CXXFLAGS += -O3
x.so: x.o y.o
    $(LINK.cc) -shared $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

Comment: Do you not need to make explicit reference to `CXXFLAGS` in the invocation? Also, why `g++` and not `$(CXX)`?

Comment: @KerrekSB 1) No. CXXFLAGS is being used in the implicit `%.o: %.cc` rule. 2) To make it simple and easy-to-understand.  But I have added the alternative that you suggest.

Comment: @user1018562 - please note that I used `CXXFLAGS` because I used C++ as my test language. You may need to use `CFLAGS` if you use C as your programming language.